# Filtering an XSD as part of a Maven build

Tags: xml, maven, jaxb, xsd, xjc

How can I produce a 'filtered' version of an XSD (ie minus certain elements) as part of a Maven build?

An API I'm working on has it's model defined by an XSD, which is turned into Java classes by XJC. I want to have annotations appear in the generated classes, and should be able to do this via the JAXB2 Basics Annotate plugin.

We may need to provide a copy of the XSD to integration partners as a definition of the API. We would not want them seeing the elements of the XSD relating to Java annotations, so it would be good if we could produce a new version of the XSD with each build that has all the annotate elements removed.

Comment: Turns out there's an easier solution - use an external bindings file to apply new rules to the existing XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSD is still an XML file. You could use an XSLT to create a version specific to your needs. The [maven xml plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) can do this as part of the build.